# how to make body height to take whole window height after scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, height

I tried

```
html,body{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
```

but it just works when I reload or revisit my Website.

What I get after scrolling:
[image]

What I want after scrolling:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help:

```
html,body{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
```

Just replace it with

```
html,body{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it worked after removing height:100% from html,body
[image]